# CW question regarding Visual Studio put "on hold"?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, list-questions

This [Community wiki question about VS language support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842728/list-of-supported-languages-and-platforms-in-visual-studio) that is arguably on topic has been put on hold, because its "too broad". I've added my own answer with support for like 20 languages, and I don't think the question is too broad.

Its obviously open to collect "broad" information, which is why the primary answer (written by me) is marked CW so anyone can edit it and improve it. What harm is this question doing by simply being open? I understand that the CW answer can still be edited, but the ugly "put on hold" notice on the top is not going to attract any more contributors.

I'd also like to know what is "off topic" about that specific questions. Attempting to create a list of languages/platforms supported by VS is off topic on SO?

Comment: So, you think "community wiki" should be a magical way of getting around the rules of what is on topic here? Sorry, but not.

Comment: So a list of languages that VS supports is considered "off topic"? How?

Comment: A "list" is off-topic. It is not a question.

Comment: CWs are weird, such questions are normally off-topic unless enough people put work into it. Imho SE should either provide a proper wiki system or get rid of the current system.

Comment: I agree with @Stijn. An example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253683/what-browsers-support-html5-websocket-api. It is locked (answers are only allowed to be edited), but not "on hold".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

List questions, while often helpful and popular, have over time become considered off topic on Stack Overflow mainly because they tend to become stale, and can be a magnet for spam.

It's a policy painful for many (including myself), but it's the current community policy and enforcing it is within the rules.

An interesting site specializing on list questions is [Slant](http://www.slant.co/).

Related discussion:

- [Exceptional cases for list questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112327/exceptional-cases-for-list-questions)
- [The halting problem - or - the fallacy of "real questions have answers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75674/the-halting-problem-or-the-fallacy-of-real-questions-have-answers)